# rqt_plot waiting for message

Tags: rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone

I am using rqt_plot in order to draw a couple variables (all floats) that come in several messages.

Problem is, some of the messages only come after some time.

So imagine I have

msg1/data,
msg2/data and
msg3/data

At start, only msg1 and msg2 are being published. After some time msg3 will also be published.

I wanted rqt_plot to draw all 3 values, but if I configure it to all msgs

rosrun rqt_plot rqt_plot /msg1/data /msg2/data /msg3/data

It will hang waiting for the first msg3 to be published:

WARNING: topic [/msg3/data] does not appear to be published yet. Waiting...

Is there a way to avoid this?

To make rqt_plot non blocking in waiting for messages?

Thanks

Miguel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/82216/rqt_plot-waiting-for-message/) by [Miguel Riem de Oliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1178/miguel-riem-de-oliveira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 254 on 2013-09-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-09-23**:
Do you think this happens with specific type of topics or happens with any kind of topics?

**Comment by [Miguel Riem de Oliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1178/miguel-riem-de-oliveira/) on 2013-10-01**:
Hi Saito

It happens with all kinds of topics, I think.

Regards Miguel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I came across this same issue.  rqt_plot saves whatever you last had displayed in a config file for "convenience" the next time that it is used.  You can fix this one of two ways easily:

(1) Clear all topics prior to exiting

(2) launch rqt_plot using: rosrun rqt_plot rqt_plot -e (the -e option stands for 'empty')

Hope that helps.  I found this very annoying myself.

- Chief

---

Originally posted by [Chief_534](https://answers.ros.org/users/5677/chief_534/) with karma: 31 on 2013-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miguel Riem de Oliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1178/miguel-riem-de-oliveira/) on 2013-10-09**:
Thanks Chief, I'll give it a try